# Apt-get throwing errors after adding apt-key

Tags: apt, kali-linux

I tried using this on Kali Linux:

https://blog.sleeplessbeastie.eu/2016/03/21/how-to-use-recent-version-of-firefox-in-debian-jessie/

to get my Firefox to update. Unfortunately now `apt-get update` throws these errors:

```
Ign:1 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
Hit:2 https://download.sublimetext.com apt/stable/ InRelease                   
Hit:3 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release                     
Hit:4 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_0.12 jessie InRelease                    
Ign:6 http://mozilla.debian.net jessie-backports InRelease                     
Hit:5 http://kali.mirror.globo.tech/kali kali-rolling InRelease          
Err:8 http://mozilla.debian.net jessie-backports Release                 
404  Not Found [IP: 5.153.231.4 80]
Reading package lists... Done                      
E: The repository 'http://mozilla.debian.net jessie-backports Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

My souces.list

```
# 

# deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 2017.1 _Kali-rolling_ - Official Snapshot amd64 L$

#deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 2017.1 _Kali-rolling_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LI$

deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main non-free contrib
# deb-src http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main non-free contrib
```

I had to add it here due to not having 10 rep.

My apt-key list

```
pub   rsa4096 2017-05-08 [SCEA]
  1EDD E2CD FC02 5D17 F6DA  9EC0 ADAE 6AD2 8A8F 901A
uid           [ unknown] Sublime HQ Pty Ltd <support@sublimetext.com>
sub   rsa4096 2017-05-08 [S]

pub   rsa4096 2014-06-13 [SC]
  9FD3 B784 BC1C 6FC3 1A8A  0A1C 1655 A0AB 6857 6280
uid           [ unknown] NodeSource <gpg@nodesource.com>
sub   rsa4096 2014-06-13 [E]

pub   dsa1024 2007-03-08 [SC]
  4CCA 1EAF 950C EE4A B839  76DC A040 830F 7FAC 5991
uid           [ unknown] Google, Inc. Linux Package Signing Key <linux-packages-keymaster@google.com>
sub   elg2048 2007-03-08 [E]

pub   rsa4096 2016-04-12 [SC]
  EB4C 1BFD 4F04 2F6D DDCC  EC91 7721 F63B D38B 4796
uid           [ unknown] Google Inc. (Linux Packages Signing Authority) <linux-packages-keymaster@google.com>
sub   rsa4096 2016-04-12 [S] [expires: 2019-04-12]

/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/debian-archive-jessie-automatic.gpg
----------------------------------------------------------
pub   rsa4096 2014-11-21 [SC] [expires: 2022-11-19]
  126C 0D24 BD8A 2942 CC7D  F8AC 7638 D044 2B90 D010
uid           [ unknown] Debian Archive Automatic Signing Key (8/jessie)<ftpmaster@debian.org>

/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/debian-archive-jessie-security-automatic.gpg
-------------------------------------------------------------------
pub   rsa4096 2014-11-21 [SC] [expires: 2022-11-19]
  D211 6914 1CEC D440 F2EB  8DDA 9D6D 8F6B C857 C906
uid           [ unknown] Debian Security Archive Automatic Signing Key (8/jessie) <ftpmaster@debian.org>

/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/debian-archive-jessie-stable.gpg
-------------------------------------------------------
pub   rsa4096 2013-08-17 [SC] [expires: 2021-08-15]
  75DD C3C4 A499 F1A1 8CB5  F3C8 CBF8 D6FD 518E 17E1
uid           [ unknown] Jessie Stable Release Key <debian-release@lists.debian.org>

/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/debian-archive-stretch-automatic.gpg
-----------------------------------------------------------
pub   rsa4096 2017-05-22 [SC] [expires: 2025-05-20]
  E1CF 20DD FFE4 B89E 8026  58F1 E0B1 1894 F66A EC98
uid           [ unknown] Debian Archive Automatic Signing Key (9/stretch) <ftpmaster@debian.org>
sub   rsa4096 2017-05-22 [S] [expires: 2025-05-20]

/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/debian-archive-stretch-security-automatic.gpg
--------------------------------------------------------------------
pub   rsa4096 2017-05-22 [SC] [expires: 2025-05-20]
  6ED6 F5CB 5FA6 FB2F 460A  E88E EDA0 D238 8AE2 2BA9
uid           [ unknown] Debian Security Archive Automatic Signing Key (9/stretch) <ftpmaster@debian.org>
sub   rsa4096 2017-05-22 [S] [expires: 2025-05-20]

/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/debian-archive-stretch-stable.gpg
--------------------------------------------------------
pub   rsa4096 2017-05-20 [SC] [expires: 2025-05-18]
  067E 3C45 6BAE 240A CEE8  8F6F EF0F 382A 1A7B 6500
uid           [ unknown] Debian Stable Release Key (9/stretch) <debian-release@lists.debian.org>

/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/debian-archive-wheezy-automatic.gpg
----------------------------------------------------------
pub   rsa4096 2012-04-27 [SC] [expires: 2020-04-25]
  A1BD 8E9D 78F7 FE5C 3E65  D8AF 8B48 AD62 4692 5553
uid           [ unknown] Debian Archive Automatic Signing Key (7.0/wheezy) <ftpmaster@debian.org>

/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/debian-archive-wheezy-stable.gpg
-------------------------------------------------------
pub   rsa4096 2012-05-08 [SC] [expires: 2019-05-07]
  ED6D 6527 1AAC F0FF 15D1  2303 6FB2 A1C2 65FF B764
uid           [ unknown] Wheezy Stable Release Key <debian-release@lists.debian.org>

/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/kali-archive-keyring.gpg
-----------------------------------------------
pub   rsa4096 2012-03-05 [SC] [expires: 2018-02-02]
  44C6 513A 8E4F B3D3 0875  F758 ED44 4FF0 7D8D 0BF6
uid           [ unknown] Kali Linux Repository <devel@kali.org>
sub   rsa4096 2012-03-05 [E] [expires: 2018-02-02]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The" [How to use recent version of Firefox in Debian Jessie](https://blog.sleeplessbeastie.eu/2016/03/21/how-to-use-recent-version-of-firefox-in-debian-jessie/)" can be used only on debian jessie

Run :

```
rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mozilla-firefox.list
apt update
```

Comment: Holly hell it works! Why is it different from manual removing it?